# How to program TopBar button press event handler?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using Wix's react-native-navigation.

their documentation says a component can listen to topper buttons events by using `Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);` as well as `navigationButtonPressed({ buttonId }) {
    // will be called when "buttonOne" is clicked
  }`

however nothing is happening. not even the original pop event.

```
export default class Lobby extends React.Component {
  static options(passProps) {
    topBar: {
      title: {
        text: "Lobby"
      },
      visible: true,
      leftButtons: [
        {
          id: "testId",
          text: "Leave",
          color:"red"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
  }
  navigationButtonPressed({ buttonId }) {
    switch(buttonId) {
      case: "testId":
        alert("test");
        socket.emit("disconnect");
        break;
    }
  }
```

`Navigation` is imported successfully.

I expect at least, the socket event to be received by the server, I also want the page to be popped and Navigated to previous page.

the alert displays, but no server event is received at all.

Comment: its an issue with using the "disconnect" event. changing the event name worked. I believe its because "disconnect" is a reserved keyword for socket.io servers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same blocker and this is how I fixed it. I used registerNavigationButtonPressedListener() and passed navigationButtonPressed

```
`constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Navigation.events().registerNavigationButtonPressedListener(this.navigationButtonPressed);
  }
  navigationButtonPressed({ buttonId }) {
    switch(buttonId) {
      case: "testId":
        alert("test");
        socket.emit("disconnect");
        break;
    }`
```